# database inaccessible and stuck in startup state

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

**Situation**

- I have 7 databases which are inaccessible.
- In the sql server error log, I see them starting up but they never
  become available.
  In sysprocesses, I see them stuck in **IO_RETRY** wait type.

  select spid, lastwaittype,cmd, status from master..sysprocesses order by spid;

[image]

**Effects**

The above situation is causes CPU consumption which increases over time.

**What do I want now?**

Remove these databases in any way possible, so that they don't consume any resources. I don't mind trying unconventional methods.

**How did they end of in such a state**

1. We used Idera Virtual restore tool to create these dbs from a backup
   file.
2. We renamed those DBs using SSMS directly.
3. DBs were still
   accessible and readable.
4. We altered some data on those dbs.
5. Now DBs
   became inaccessible.
6. We kills spids and restarted sql server without
   patience.
7. Now Idera virtual restore service cannot remove them,
   neither can we drop them.
8. Sql server cannot bring them up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What do I want now?
>   Remove these databases in any way possible, so that they don't consume any resources. **I don't mind trying unconventional methods**.

To remove them just stop SQL Server and delete MDF and LOG files. I assume you have good backups.

Comment: I didn't care about those databases, so this solution was perfect. Thank you.